# eclipse indigo - windowbuilder - eclipse doesn't regain focus

Tags: linux, eclipse, gwt, windowbuilder

I have eclipse 3.7 indigo; I installed gwt plugin and its designer; The problem is (time after time) when I add new widget X to composite the

- palette (keeps widget selected)
- components (doesn't show the new widget in the tree)
- properties (doesn't show the new widget properties)

...so I cannot select another widget unless I resize the whole eclipse application to force its GUI repaint :(
It seems like palette and other managers don't get report *"widget was added from windowbuilder"* or similar :(

*Moreover, I cannot edit widget's text if I have input method as "System" which is the default on btw so the only one input method which works is "X Input Method" but anyways it doesn't solve the mentioned focus regain problem;*

That makes eclipse indigo really hard to use; So my question is... how to fix that?

p.s.

eclipse 3.7 (indigo)

- gwt plugin - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/archive/3.6.0/3.7
- gwt designer - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7
- gwt sdk 2.2
- jdk 1.7
- jre 1.7
- OS Linux x64

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do my own research concerning the issue; I noticed there is some kind of "jobs order conflict" or similar with the default constructor based code style as :

```
public class MyTestUI extends Composite {
    private FlowPanel flowPanel;

    public MyTestUI() {

        flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        initWidget(flowPanel);

    }

}
```

...so, as a workaround, I had to play with code generator as;

> window -> preferences -> windowbuilder -> gwt

- (combobox) method name for new statements : **initComponents**
- variable generation : **field**
- statement generation : **flat**

just to avoid having in-constructor init as a result I have code generated as :

```
public class MyTestUI extends Composite {
    private FlowPanel flowPanel;

    public MyTestUI() {     
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {

        flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        initWidget(flowPanel);
    }


}
```

*...btw there is a problem with focus regain if input method is "System" and initComponents() method generated first time; so before starting adding widgets I had to select "X input method" to avoid synch-ed jobs; So "X input method" needs to be the default one, as I can get it :)*

**EDIT** : 
The effect I faced very looks like [bug 388170](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388170); So I tried to modify eclipse.ini argument as

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

It seems like the **headless** helps a bit but anyways eclipse sometimes does hang when using windowbuilder especially DnD :P

---

Anyways I want to point I faced the mentioned issue first time cause similar windows x32 eclipse indigo version works pretty fine with gwt;

p.s.
The solution is not final *(the hang problem still occurs on DnD evens)* and I am still looking for a more optimal one; So do comment if you have some helpful tips or ideas;